# Avoid namespace in the XML response (tags)

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces

We are pulling data from Cisco ips (SDEE server) using Java. Its a normal web request and we are using HttpsURLConnection. The response is in the form of an XML.

We have a UI (web app) that can trigger the job to pull the data; we also have a standalone utility that can also trigger the job to pull the data. So, the code to retrieve data from the sdee server is same in both the cases. Using Quartz to schedule a job, though this info is irrelevant here.

Now the problem - when the job is triggered from the UI, we get expected xml, no issues. But when the job is triggered using the utility, we get the same xml but with namespace within its tags.

```
<['http://example.org/2003/08/sdee']:sd:evIdsAlert eventId='123' vendor='Cisco' severity='low'><['http://example.org/2003/08/sdee']:sd:originator>
```

['http://example.org/2003/08/sdee'] - this is something extra we are getting. We don't want this in the XML.

As the code is same, I suspect that may be some environment settings is affecting the response, but I don't know what.

Some part of the code (that we are using), just for reference:

```
// get the connection
connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
// get the reader
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
// read response line by line and dump it to the file
```

The code is pretty simple - a standard one to pull the data using HTTP(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to different xml parsers. Its fixed now.